# How can I wait for the result of menu opened manually?

Tags: c#, winforms

Normally a menu is opened by click right mouse button(this part is handled easily),yet sometimes I need to open the menu automatically and wait for the user to choose an item. My approach like this:

```
//let menu be a ContextMenuStrip
//newlyCreatedObject be a object set by menu's click event handler
public Object createNewObject()
{
    menu.show();         //this line should block until menu close,but it didn't 
    return newlyCreatedObject;   //ERROR:immediately return before event handler run
}
```

Ideally the menu.show() part should act like a MFC Dialog's DoModal() that handle all the menu's interaction and return when menu is closed. After that i can get the newlyCreatedObject and do whatever i want with it.
So my question is how can i wait the menu to finish,before return newlyCreatedObject?

PS:I am trying to write a UE4 blueprint like application. In UE4 Blueprint you could either click right mouse button to show up a menu and choose what to add or **drag a link out of a pin and release button to show up a menu and link the newly added function automatically(this part is what I want to achieve)**. I guess it would be possible to break up the create part and link part, but this must lead to a lot of state condition.

Comment: Why do you need to return something? you should have a `void OpenMenu(){}` method and another one for `EventHandler` that will react to selection

Comment: There is only one way to force this kind of modal UI behavior onto a user in Winforms: ShowDialog().  For all other cases you need to do what you already know, move code into the Click event handler.

Comment: Winforms: ShowDialog() is what i want,I have changed the menu to a winform with buttons, but the code looks messy. Wish there's a ShowDialog() like function for menu.